# Ionic - Ionic Serve not working, blank page

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an application under the Ionic framework. After trying to inject a function in a state in a .js file corresponding to a page of my application, I encountered a very strange problem.

My Ionic Serve refreshed and became blank and I had this message written when I tried a new Ionic Serve command :

```
[WARN] Error with .\www\lib\ionic\version.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND, trying .\bower.json.
```

I already checked the Internet, I deleted my node_modules folder and did npm install after. The warning has disappeared but Ionic Serve still gives me a blank page instead of my index.html.

Here is my 'ionic info' output :

```
$ ionic info
[WARN] Error with .\www\lib\ionic\version.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND, trying 
.\bower.json.
[WARN] Error with .\www\lib\ionic\version.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND, trying 
.\bower.json.

cli packages: (C:\Users\RAPH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1

local packages:

Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.4

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v10.2.1
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 7

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\RAPH\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Misc:

backend : pro
```

Please help me to resolve this problem, I need to finish my work for sunday. I would be very grateful and if I can help you on something else don't hesitate to ask in return

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you're entire code block looks?

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index");
  $stateProvider
    .state("index", {
      url: "/index",
      templateUrl: "index.html"
    })
    .state("menu", {
      url: "/menu",
      templateUrl: "menu.html"
    })
    .state("indication_patient", {
      url: "/indication_patient",
      templateUrl: "indication_patient.html"
    })
    .state("competition", {
      url: "/competition",
      templateUrl: "competition.html"
    })
    .state("patient", {
      url: "/patient",
      templateUrl: "patient.html"
    })
    .state("athlete", {
      url: "/athlete",
      templateUrl: "athlete.html"
    });
});
```

Comment: This didn't work but you were right, it was a syntax error ! You just have to put the ";" after the last state and not at the end. Thanks for your contribution, don't hesitate to ask for any help too.

Comment: Cool. Accept my answer however. Helps close the question

Answer (score -1):

try to download cors google chrome extension and install it in ur google chrome and re run the "ionic serve" command with the extension being turned on in google chrome

here is the link :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: this link even not existing